# Point from Domain to IP with A Record

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, dns

I bought a Domain (www.example.com) and created a A Record in order to point to my webserver (81.11.12.13). My Webpage is in a subfolder (because I want to run two different pages with this webserver). I redirect the user to the right folder with the following .htaccess rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch ^/$ /shop/
```

Problem I have right now is that after the redirect the URL displays the IP from the server instead of the human-readable-domain-name.

Right now I get `http://81.11.12.13/shop` instead of `http:www.example.com/shop`

Is it possible to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably close, the following should do it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*) http://hostname/shop/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I've added the full domain to the redirect; it also adds the `[]` component at the end, which will ensure that the redirect is set as permanent with a header (good for search engines), and "L" which is meant to indicate the end of this particular rule chain (as you may add other rules in future).

If you want to serve two different sites from a single server I'd also look at [Apache Virtual Hosts](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) which is a bit more comprehensive as it will split your config, logging etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this doesn't work because it says `Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

Comment: @JohnBrunner I've made a few changes and tested on http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ to ensure it works, let me know!

Comment: Thank you. But this statement basically attaches unlimited `shop` strings to my URL (http://www.domain.com/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/). Do you think my problem is solvable in theory?

Comment: I'll have a go again; it's likely I need to add a `RewriteCond` line to exclude `/shop` if it's already there but I can't seem to get the syntax correct. Looking into Virtual Hosts (as linked in my answer) is definitely the preferred way to do this; it gives you a lot more logging and other control.